# Type is not assignable to type T

Tags: typescript

```
export function getBlank<T extends { results: any[] }>(): Observable<T> {
  const response: T = { results: [] };
  return of(response);
}
```

is failing to compile with error

```
Type '{ results: undefined[]; }' is not assignable to type 'T'.ts(2322)
```

Please help, whats wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
export function getBlank<T extends { results: any[] }>(): Observable<T> {
  const response: T = { results: [] };
  return of(response);
}
```

The code in this function must pass type-checking for any user-provided type `T` which extends `{ results: any[] }`, for example this one:

```
const o = getBlank<{result: any[]; moreResults: any[]}>();
```

But with this `T`, this assignment is not valid because `moreResults` is missing:

```
const response: T = { results: [] };
```

In general, you can't use generic parameter `T` for any variables created in the body of the generic function, unless you use constructor or some other function, usually provided as a parameter, which is declared to return appropriately initialized value for any possible `T`.